# StickyHeaders is fixed when table is horizontally scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have a huge table with vast amounts of columns, which is inserted within a div element with an overflow property set to auto. I am using StickyHeaders widget (a widget for the fork of TableSorter plugin by @Mottie) and couldn't make stickyHeaders scroll with the table body.

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto">
  <table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Row ID</th>
        <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Numeric</th>
        <th>Animals</th>
        <th>Sites</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
        <td>abc 123</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
        <td>abc 1</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Ox</td>
        <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Girafee</td>
        <td>http://www.facebook.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
        <td>zyx 24</td>
        <td>767</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Bison</td>
        <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row5</td>
        <td>abc 11</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Chimp</td>
        <td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row6</td>
        <td>abc 2</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Elephant</td>
        <td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row7</td>
        <td>abc 9</td>
        <td>155</td>
        <td>Lion</td>
        <td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row8</td>
        <td>ABC 10</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Zebra</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row9</td>
        <td>zyx 1</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.mit.edu/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row10</td>
        <td>zyx 12</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>Llama</td>
        <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
 <div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
    usNumberFormat: false,
    sortReset: true,
    sortRestart: true
});
```

To demonstrate the problem, I have put it into jsfiddle. Scroll down the table, and then scroll horizontally.
Problem Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0088y5ba/4/

Same problem here ([How to use tablesorter stickyheaders widget - not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641658/how-to-use-tablesorter-stickyheaders-widget-not-working)) is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is an issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/491) when a stickyHeaders table is contained in a div with no set height, I just haven't had the time to work on it.

- One solution is to add a height to the div wrapper ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0088y5ba/7/))

  HTML

  ```
  <div class="wrapper">
      <table class="tablesorter">
      ...
      </table>
  <div>
  ```

  CSS

  ```
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  ```

  Script

  ```
  $('table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
      widgetOptions: {
          stickyHeaders_attachTo: $('.wrapper')
      },
      usNumberFormat: false,
      sortReset: true,
      sortRestart: true
  });
  ```
- A second solution, if your user base supports it, is to use the [cssStickyHeaders widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html) where no extra changes are needed ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0088y5ba/6/))

  ```
  $('table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'cssStickyHeaders', 'filter'],
      usNumberFormat: false,
      sortReset: true,
      sortRestart: true
  });
  ```